# How can I change a smart contract if I am not its creator but only a direct participant?

Tags: web3js

I am a direct participant in a smart contract and I would like to know if I could become the caller from the called party. Could the caller's address be changed to the callee's address in a smart contract, and if so, how to do it?

Comment: well it depends who has the access to that, if its only owner then you can't

Answer (score 0):

Technically a contract cannot impersonate another account. It depends on how the contracts validates the caller.

- A contract could require a signature to validate authorization.
- Create a contract for each user that could be controlled by a protocol.

Comment: Because thanks to one smart contract, my friend and I and our families lost a lot of money. Unfortunately, we didn't know that it was a contract thanks to which some fraudster has been robbing people all over the world of money for three years. Unfortunately, we found out too late. That is why I am asking whether such a contract can be canceled or reversed in some way. Every contract can be canceled in some way, so it must also be possible for a smart contract. Nothing is indestructible, and we also want to prevent the scum who does this from continuing to do it.

Comment: I don't know why someone can be so blunt and continue to rob people. My God, he stole more than eleven billion dollars in those three years. God knows what he wants to use it for.

Comment: @BoženaMichalíková If you have been victim of a scam you should contact your local authorities. The persons behind the contract are responsible for the damages. Contracts in the Ethereum blockchain are immutable and cannot be modified without violating the consensus mechanism.

Comment: My friend and I contacted our police, and so far it is being resolved, but unfortunately, we probably don't have such perfect experts to deal with it. I don't know what to do yet, so I'm trying to find a way